# MLPClassifier in Azure ML webservice call

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a model using MLPClassifier from scikitlearn. I pkl, zip it and uploaded to Azure ML. The process works fine with no errors when I run it, but once I call it from a WebService I get the following error. I also added the scikit learn files to the model so I can use MLPClassifier.

```
$ "C:\pyhome\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in find_class __import__(module, level=0) ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.neural_network.multilayer_perceptron' $
```

This is my python code in Azure ML

```
$ import sys
sys.path.insert(0, ".\\Script Bundle")    
import os
os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.dirname(".\\Script Bundle\\DLLs\\")+ ';' + os.environ['PATH']
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.externals import joblib
#from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    
    #print ("sklearn version :", sk.__version__)
    model = joblib.load('./Script Bundle/RNNmodel.pkl')
    y_train = model.predict(dataframe1)
    dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(y_train)
    return dataframe1,
$
```

Comment: What's your output of `sk.__version__` when you run in AML dashoard?  Is it `0.18.x` as your custom package or `0.17.1` as the default version in AML's python runtime?

Comment: the output is 0.18. I solved the problem partially. I originally had two "Execute python script" boxes. One of them using python 0.17.1 and the second one using 0.18. This config works if I execute the experiment online, but it won't if I call it from the web service. I consolidated everything into only one "Execute Python script" with 0.18 and that works, even though is not my ideal. I tried using the 2 with 0.18 but got a "memory denied access" error.

Comment: @RodrigoCoronado,thanks for your comments. I wonder know how do you set the sklearn version as 0.18 on Azure ML environment ?